# How to send an array object to service api in flutter using retrofit?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

I am using retrofit to call my API's.
Following is the body I wish to send:

```
{
    "answer_data": [{
        "_id":"6311e21b3627de0d98362012",
        "answer":"Testing"
    },
    {
        "_id":"6311e21b3627de0d98362013",
        "answer":"Testing123"
    }]
}
```

Following is my app_api.dart file code:

```
@POST("/publicQuestionSubmit")
  Future<DeliveryResponse> postSurveyDeliveryResponse(
      @Field("answer_data") List<PostSurveyDeliveryQuestions> postQuestions);
```

Following is the PostSurveyDeliveryQuestions class:

```
class PostSurveyDeliveryQuestions{
  String questionId, answer;

  PostSurveyDeliveryQuestions(this.questionId,this.answer);
}
```

What changes should I make in this post method to send an array object?

Answer (score 0):

firstly encode the Data into json Then send it for post body

```
String jsonBody = jsonEncode(array);
Response response = await post(url , body : jsonBody);
```